# Login Function stuck on loop

Tags: javascript

I'm making a simple ATM for a class and I need to make a login function which locks you out after 3 tries and now, it seems to be stuck asking for your user and pass until you run out of tries. When successful it should call my menu function and add a bit of text to a stack I'm using as a log of the operations you do while logged in.

```js
function login(pin_daniel,pin_stephanie,pin_cano,log){
    var ingreso = false;
    var intentos = 1;
    while (intentos != 3 && ingreso == false){
        var usuario = prompt("Bienvenido a CanoBank, su banco de `confianza`, por favor ingrese su usuario y pin\n"+
            "Usuario:");
        var pin_login = prompt("PIN:");
        if (usuario == 'daniel' && pin_login == pin_daniel){
            ingreso = true;
            menu(daniel_dinero_ahorro,daniel_dinero_monetaria);
            log.push(usuario + "entro al sistema" + Date.now())
        }
        else if (usuario == 'stephanie' && pin_login == pin_stephanie){
            ingreso = true;
            menu(stephanie_dinero_ahorro,stephanie_dinero_monetaria);
            log.push(usuario + "entro al sistema" + Date.now())
        }
        else if (usuario == 'cano' && pin_login == pin_cano){
            ingreso = true;
            menu(cano_dinero_ahorro,cano_dinero_monetaria);
            log.push(usuario + "entro al sistema" + Date.now())
        }
        else{
            console.log("Usuario o PIN incorrecto, tiene" + ( 3 - intentos) + "oportunidades");
            intentos = intentos + 1;
        }
    }

}
login();
```

Comment: Try splitting your conditions (usuario == user && pin_login == pin_user) into separate checks to try to find the problem. Since we don't know the values for pin_logins and don't know how the 'prompt' function works, we can't help much.

Comment: prompt is same as input in other languages and the pins are just 1234 for now, I tried to make it as a real login where you have to match both for it to let you in,

Comment: In your login() function, you don't appear to be passing in the passwords?

Comment: yeah, they're the pin_x variables which you compare in the ifs.

Comment: Right, but when you call 'login();' at the very bottom, you aren't providing the pins to the function. So you're comparing input to an uninitialized variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing:

```
login();
```

to:

```
login('1234','1234','1234', log);
```

You need to pass in variables containing the actual pins so the comparisons to the user supplied input are valid.

Of course, this is not how it should be done in practice. It is just an example illustrating how to use functions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question.

But if your question is: "Why does my log do not contains trace of the logging when it is sucessful until a quit the menu?"

The the answer would be: "because Javascript is sequential and that if the login is successful, the menu function is called before the appending into the log. Si you need to wait for your menu function to return, to add your line to the log, try to do the opposite, and it will be ok"

Comment: Thanks for the sequential bit, didn't remember that, my question is: I have a login, which should kick out out if you get the login wrong 3 times but now it's stuck on a loop where it will ask you to login and even if you're right will continue asking until you hit that limit and kicks you out.